# How to calculate the energy and correlation of an image

Tags: image, matlab, image-processing, feature-extraction, entropy

Could anyone help me how to calculate the energy and correlation of an image using MATLAB?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are looking for [`graycomatrix`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/graycomatrix.html) and [`graycoprops`](http://www.mathworks.com/help/images/ref/graycoprops.html).  From the `graycoprops` documentation, two properties that can be computed:

```
'Correlation'   statistical measure of how correlated a pixel is to its 
                neighbor over the whole image. Range = [-1 1]. 
                Correlation is 1 or -1 for a perfectly positively or
                negatively correlated image. Correlation is NaN for a 
                constant image.

'Energy'        summation of squared elements in the GLCM. Range = [0 1].
                Energy is 1 for a constant image.
```

To compute these properties, first compute the graylevel co-occurrence matrix via `graycomatrix`, then call `graycoprops`.  For example,

```
I = imread('circuit.tif');
GLCM = graycomatrix(I,'Offset',[2 0;0 2]);
stats = graycoprops(GLCM,{'correlation','energy'})
```

You just need to decide on the `Offset` parameter for `graycomatrix`. A thorough choice would be `offset = [0 1; -1 1; -1 0; -1 -1];`

---

To compute entropy for the GLCMs, you can't use `graycoprops`, so you'll have to do it yourself:

```
p = bsxfun(@rdivide,GLCM,sum(sum(GLCM,1),2)); % normalize each GLCM to probs

numGLCMs = size(p,3);
entropyVals = zeros(1,numGLCMs);
for ii=1:numGLCMs,
    pi = p(:,:,ii);
    entropyVals(ii) = -sum(pi(pi>0).*log(pi(pi>0)));
end
```

Comment: thank you dude. Could you please suggest to calculate for entropy

Comment: @Matlab_Begineer Generally, you'd post a different question, but I added it to my answer.